# Use C#.Net 2010 to invoke methods on a remote web service and use its data

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, web-services, soap

I'm creating a windows application on Visual Studio .Net 2010 with C#. There's a working Web service on the internet with API methods. Here's an example of one of them, they work with SOAP messages: 
So you enter a username and password string on this SOAP request:

```
POST /anp.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: api.anp.se
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://api.anp.se/GetOptOutList"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetOptOutList xmlns="http://api.anp.se/">
      <strUsername>string</strUsername>
      <strPassword>string</strPassword>
      <strMailingListID>string</strMailingListID>
    </GetOptOutList>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And the format of the SOAP response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetOptOutListResponse xmlns="http://api.anp.se/">
      <GetOptOutListResult>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</GetOptOutListResult>
    </GetOptOutListResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And when you click on the invoke button, the online service returns an XML dataset, here's a snippet of the result:

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://api.anp.se/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Report">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="SendQueueID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="SendTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Subject" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="SubscriberCount" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="MailingList" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Report diffgr:id="Report1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<SendQueueID>1235163</SendQueueID>
<SendTime>2011-06-20T12:26:54.25+02:00</SendTime>
<Subject>Tack för din bokning</Subject>
<SubscriberCount>939</SubscriberCount>
<MailingList>Tack för din bokning 2011-06-20</MailingList>
</Report>
<Report diffgr:id="Report2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<SendQueueID>1235146</SendQueueID>
<SendTime>2011-06-20T12:15:55.62+02:00</SendTime>
<Subject>Välkommen hem</Subject>
<SubscriberCount>688</SubscriberCount>
<MailingList>Välkommen hem 2011-06-20</MailingList>
</Report>
<Report diffgr:id="Report3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<SendQueueID>1235128</SendQueueID>
<SendTime>2011-06-20T12:08:54.277+02:00</SendTime>
<Subject>Trevlig resa</Subject>
<SubscriberCount>832</SubscriberCount>
<MailingList>Trevlig resa 2011-06-20</MailingList>
</Report>
<Report diffgr:id="Report4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
<SendQueueID>1232232</SendQueueID>
<SendTime>2011-06-17T12:07:54.767+02:00</SendTime>
<Subject>Tack för din bokning</Subject>
<SubscriberCount>398</SubscriberCount>
<MailingList>Tack för din bokning 2011-06-17</MailingList>
</Report>
```

If you're referring me to a tutorial, please make sure it's straight to the point and useful because I've seen lots of them that cannot help me. I need to work with the data set. How can I obtain the dataset object and how can I access the data inside it? Do I have to add service preferences to my project and what type of .Net project should it be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not skilled enough to tell you *how* to do it, but I know that you can query XML using LINQ in C#/VB, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2):

Just about any type of C# project should work. You just need to right-click on the project and select "Add Service Reference". Then you can put the url into the Address textbox, give it a name, and hit ok. This should create a service proxy class containing everything you need, including all the classes returned by the service.

I haven't done this in a long time.  This ***very* basic** example uses the Dilbert Web Service:

```
DilbertSoapClient client = new DilbertSoapClient();
string s = client.DailyDilbert(DateTime.Now);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(s);
table.ReadXml(reader);
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    // do something with the row
}
```

Of course, I don't have the webservice you are actually using, so dealing with it may vary a bit, but this is the basic model.

Comment: hey, I know the questions is a couple of years old, but is it not possible to provide the address to the SOAP WSDL at runtime?